# How to return pointer in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, reference

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *link;
}hop;

main()
{
    int c;
    hop *m,*t;
    m=(hop *)malloc(sizeof (hop));
    m->val=10;
    t=change_val(m);
    printf("%d",t->val);
}

hop *change_val(node* m)
{
    m->val=20;
    return m;
}
```

But I got error in the function and assignment. I have tried changing the signs before the m. I tried using double pointer too. Help me.

Comment: Change `main()` to `int main(void)`. Use consistent names for the struct tag and typedef; there's no obvious relationship between `node` and `hop`, though they refer to exactly the same thing. Consider dropping the typedef altogether, and just referring to the type as `struct node`. Your malloc call can be made simpler and more robust to future code changes: `m = malloc(sizeof *m);`. If you call `malloc`, you need `#include <stdlib.h>`. Your compiler *should* have warned you about that; crank up the warning level until it does.

Comment: And don't forget to initialize the `link` member of a structure.  If your code compiled, it must have been compiled by a compiler similar to a C++ compiler (except that those require all functions to be declared before they're used), because the `hop *change_val(node *m)` should not compile in C because the type `node` is never declared (but a C++ compiler would recognize `node` after `struct node` is declared).

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare your function before you use it:

```
hop *change_val(hop* m);

int main()
{
.....
```

, be consistent with what you name your struct, don't cast the return of `malloc`, provide a return type for `main`, `free` the memory you allocated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for error is you have incorrect type for `node` in the function definition.

Either use:

```
hop *change_val(struct node* m)
{
...
}
```

OR

```
hop *change_val(hop* m)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Here's the demo after fixing it: http://ideone.com/BnL1d5